# Move a picture box faster and faster with a timer on click in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class assignment to move a picturebox randomly across the form.  Once you click on the picturebox, it is supposed to scream and change the picture then change it back to the original picture. When you click again, it is supposed to go faster.  I have it working up to the point of making it go faster.  Here is my code:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tm1.Interval = 1000;
        tm1.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
    }
        Timer tm1 = new Timer();

        int X = 0;
        int Y = 0;

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Mimikyu;
            Application.DoEvents();
            pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = true;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.screa);
            sp.PlaySync();
            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Evee;
        }
        else
            timer1.Start();
    }

    private void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int X = ((int)(new Random().Next(0, 1000)));
        int Y = ((int)(new Random().Next(0, 500)));

        if (X > 1025 - pictureBox1.Width)
            {
                X = 1025 - pictureBox1.Width;
            }
        if (Y > 545 - pictureBox1.Height)
            {
                Y = 545 - pictureBox1.Height;
            }
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    }
}
```

}

Point me to where I need to go to get the interval to move faster and faster after each click  Thank you.

Comment: You have to model the *velocity* of the object.  The rate of change over time.  In this snippet that's produced by the arguments to Random.Next().  The higher the value you pass, the larger the result on average and thus the faster the box will move.  So don't hard-code 1000, use a variable.  You'll also have to learn how to use the Random class properly (create it just once).

Answer (score 0):

decreasing the tm1.Interval should do it

```
  ...
    else
    if (tm1.Interval>10){tm1.Interval -= 10;} 
    timer1.Start();
```